# Build a dynamic hierarchy tree in Visulforce using VF Components

Tags: apex, visualforce, visualforce-component, hierarchy

I'm trying to create a tree hierarchy in Visualforce using a Visualforce component in order to be able to reuse as much code as I can and make it as dynamic as possible. I'll post my code below, but keep in mind that this is work in progress, I just wanted to create a `proof of concept` code initially.

My initial idea was to have a wrapper class like this:

```
public with sharing class OrderLineWrapper {
    public OrderLineWrapper() {
        ChildOrderLines = new Map<Id, OrderLineWrapper>();
    }

    public String ParentServiceOrder {get; set;}
    public String ParentOrderLine {get; set;}
    public Map<Id, OrderLineWrapper> ChildOrderLines {get; set;}
    public Order_Line__c OrderLine {get; set;}

    public OrderLineWrapper get(Id key)
    {
        return ChildOrderLines.get(key);
    }

    public List<OrderLineWrapper> values()
    {
        return ChildOrderLines.values();
    }
}
```

A Visualforce page that will host a component and provided it with initial Root Node:

```
<apex:page showHeader="true" sidebar="true"
    extensions="DisconnectServiceOrderLineHierarchy">

    <c:GenericOrderLineHierarchyComponent parentnode="{!OrderLineHierarchy}"></c:GenericOrderLineHierarchyComponent>

</apex:page>
```

And finally I have my recursive component:

```
<apex:component >
    <apex:attribute name="parentnode" description="Parent node for component"
                    type="OrderLineWrapper" required="true"/>

    --{!parentnode.OrderLine.Name}
    <apex:repeat value="{!parentnode.ChildOrderLines}" var="key">
        <br/>
        <c:GenericOrderLineHierarchyComponent parentnode="{!parentnode.ChildOrderLines[key]}"></c:GenericOrderLineHierarchyComponent>
    </apex:repeat>
</apex:component>
```

However, my component won't compile because of the following error:

> Cyclic page or component references
>   '/apexcomponent/c__genericorderlinehierarchycomponent' are not allowed

Does anybody know any workaround for this? Is there any sample code out there that demonstrates how to build a dynamic hierarchy tree in Visulforce?

Comment: I used [jQuery treetable](http://ludo.cubicphuse.nl/jquery-treetable/#examples) for this. where the parent-child relationships are modelled as data attributes in the HTML. The page/code is too big to post here. No nested components in it.

Comment: +1 to Keith comment, except I was using ExtJS and tree grid. But you can also try to use apex dynamic component - https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_dynamicComponent.htm

Comment: Thank you guys for ideas and suggestions that I should look for an alternative approach. I managed to implement this with Angular, using `ng-repeat` and `ng-template`.